# What are the algebraic procedures from $0.127mm \times 92^{36-n\over 39}$ to $e^{2.1104-0.11594n}mm$?

Tags: calculus

What are the algebraic procedures from $0.127mm \times 92^{36-n\over 39}$ to $e^{2.1104-0.11594n}mm$?
$$$$Thank you in advance

Comment: What does this mean?

Comment: How to show that those two numbers are equal? Was taken from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_wire_gauge#Formula

Comment: It is an approximation. If $n=0$, then the lhs is 8.25146... and the rhs is 8.25154...

Comment: But how it was made? Simply using graph?

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: These numbers are not equal-they are close.  It would have been helpful to state that, and to say it is an approximation on AWG as you did in the comment.  Mathematicians (as opposed to engineers) think equality is sacred.  On this site, $\sqrt 2 \neq 1.414$

Comment: @RossMillikan I'd point out that 4 or 5 digit decimal numbers is usually a dead giveaway that inexact numbers are in use, or even really any usage of decimals, full stop (no pun intended). If you wanted to say $1/2$, would you say $\frac12$ or $0.5$? In my mind, the second answer has some suggestion that the number may not be exactly $1/2$, whereas the first is certainly exact.

Answer (score 1):

The number is $(0.127 92^{\frac{36}{39}}) 92^{\frac{-n}{39}}$.

If $e^a = 0.127 92^{\frac{36}{39}}$, then $a = \ln(0.127 92^{\frac{36}{39}}) \approx 2.11039$, and if $e^{-bn} = 92^{\frac{-n}{39}}$, then $-bn = - \frac{n}{39} \ln 92$, or $b = \frac{1}{39} \ln 92 \approx 0.11594$.

Hence $(0.127 92^{\frac{36}{39}}) 92^{\frac{-n}{39}} \approx e^{2.11039-0.11594n}$.

Answer (score 0):

We have $0.127=e^{\ln(0.127)}$ and $92=e^{\ln(92)}$. Since $e^x\times e^y=e^{x+y}$, and $(e^s)^t=e^{st}$, our expression is equal to 
$$e^{\ln(0.127)+\ln(92)\left(\frac{36-n}{39}\right)}.$$` 
The exponent simplifies to 
$$\ln(0.127)+\ln(92)\frac{36}{39}-\frac{\ln(92)}{39}n.$$
Now it is a matter of plugging into the calculator. My calculator says that the coefficient of $n$ in the exponent is approximately $-0.1159433$. The authors rounded off a bit more than my calculator, In my calculator, the constant term of the exponent is approximately $2.1103905$.

Comment: You are welcome. I hope it is clear where the algebraic facts I quoted are used. I can supply more detail if I was too terse.

Answer (score 0):

My preferred way of thinking about this kind of question is that $\exp(\cdot)$ and $\ln(\cdot)$ cancel each other out.

$$\begin{align}
0.127 \times 92^{36-n\over 39}&=\exp(\ln(0.127 \times 92^{36-n\over 39}))\\
&=\exp(\ln(0.127) +\ln(92^{36-n\over 39}))\\
&=\exp(\ln(0.127) +{36-n\over 39}\ln(92))\\
&=\exp\left(\ln(0.127) +{36\over 39}\ln(92) -n{\ln(92)\over 39}\right)
\end{align}$$

plug in above numbers

Comment: @ Sachin_ruk Thank you very much!